# How to load balance based on request URI ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using elastic load balancer. Now i want to do load balance based on URI checking.

Now i have group of instances and i want to redirect to that specific group of instances.

For an example

If i send post request to one instance like this
http://www.example.com/group1 with custom header data so now this request should be redirect this request to group1 server using load balancer.

If i send post request to same instance like this
http://www.example.com/group2 with custom header data so now this request should be redirected to group2 server using load balancer.

In short i want to do conditional load balancing.

So how can i do so ?

Comment: I would actually question the architecture first.  If you have some specific logic which need to run only on one specific server or set of servers, you should probably put it on it's own domain or subdomain and have it's own load balancer in front of it.  You are in essence defeating the purpose of having a load balancer in the first place as you would be artificially unbalancing the loads across the load balancer unless you have nearly equal numbers of requests between those two URI's.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to do this .

1. As conditional load balancing is not supported by Amazon, you can create two loadbalancers , one having group1 instances and another one group2 instances. Now you will have to route the traffic using Route53. Define a Cname record or A record with alias as load balancer A record name. One prob is that I am not sure if uri http://www.example.com/group1 & http://www.example.com/group2 will work , but http://www.group1.example.com/ and http://www.group2.example.com/ will surely work.
2. Another option is to handle the request from your server (ec2 instance) . You will have to redirect the request if group1 request reaches group2 server and vice versa. In this case you wont be needing 2 load balancers.

Comment: Since you can point CNAMES to Aliases, you don't need to use route53, but you would have to use dns1.example.com and dns2.example.com